# How to fix the exclude with Q & Q in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a simple query with filter and exclude. Exclude for Q & Q not working.

Below is the query that I am using.

```
start_date = (datetime(time.localtime().tm_year, time.localtime().tm_mon, 1) - timedelta(1)).replace(day=1)

data = models.Test.objects.filter(
            is_deleted=False).exclude(Q(status__in=[1,2,3]) & Q(modified_at__lt=start_date))\
            .select_related('created_by')\
            .prefetch_related('name')
```

I want the exclude to work. If I use exclude twice, I'm getting the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**From the doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

> **`exclude(**kwargs)`**
>   Returns a new **QuerySet** containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.
>   The lookup parameters **(**kwargs)** should be in the format described in [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id4) below. **Multiple parameters are joined via `AND` in the underlying SQL statement, and the whole thing is enclosed in a `NOT()`.**

So, just use **`Q()`** objects with ***comma seperation***,

```
.exclude(Q(status__in=[1,2,3],Q(modified_at__lt=start_date))
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.